# How to disable istio-proxy sidecar access log for specific deployments in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar

I'm using istio-proxy sidecar with Kubernetes, sidecars are automatically added to the Kubernetes pods.
I want to turn off the access log for one single deployment (without disabling the sidecar).
is there an annotation to do that?

Comment: Could you try to exec into your deployment with `kubectl exec` and try with this command `curl -X POST http://localhost:15000/logging?level=off `? There is envoy documentation about [that](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/admin#post--logging).

Comment: I have many pods, it has to be part of the deployment

Comment: That's the only way I know, other would be with istioctl as mentioned in [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#disable-envoy-s-access-logging), but that's gonna disable it globally.

Comment: if that so, init container that executes the curl post request can maybe do the trick

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in comments

---

If you want to disable envoy’s access logging globally you can use istioctl/operator to do that.

There is istio [documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/logs/access-log/#disable-envoy-s-access-logging) about that.

> Remove, or set to "", the meshConfig.accessLogFile setting in your Istio install configuration.

There is istioctl command:

```
istioctl install --set meshConfig.accessLogFile=""
```

There is an example with istio operator:

```
apiVersion: install.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: IstioOperator
spec:
  profile: default
  meshConfig:
    accessLogFile: ""
```

---

If you want to disable it for a specific pod you can use use below command, there is envoy [documentation](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/operations/admin#post--logging) about that.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:15000/logging?level=off
```

---

As you're looking for a way to do that for deployment that trick with [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) and above curl command might actually work.

Comment: actually, I'm not sure that init container will work because the init container starts before the istio-proxy container, so the istio-proxy will not be available yet while executing the init-container process